# bokeh 2.0 Dropdown missing value attribute

Tags: python, bokeh

**bokeh 1.4.0**

```
>>> import bokeh
>>> bokeh.__version__
'1.4.0'
>>> from bokeh.models import Dropdown
>>> Dropdown().value is None
True
```

**bokeh 2.0**

```
>>> import bokeh
>>> bokeh.__version__
'2.0.0'
>>> from bokeh.models import Dropdown
>>> Dropdown().value is None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Dropdown' object has no attribute 'value'
```

**Is there another attribute that is meant to be used now in place of value?**

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39100095/how-to-capture-value-of-dropdown-widget-in-bokeh-python) for a use-case of the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dropdown.value` was an implementation detail that was not meant to be used by Bokeh users, according to its docstring. Apart from that, `Dropdown` semantically is just a collection of buttons. It should not have *any* sort of state, it should just dispatch the `on_click` event as a regular button, just as it does in 2.0. And that's why the `value` attribute has been removed in 2.0.0.

In order to trigger Python code on a dropdown button click, you can use something like

```py
from bokeh.models import Dropdown

d = Dropdown(label='Click me', menu=['a', 'b', 'c'])


def handler(event):
    print(event.item)


d.on_click(handler)
```

`event.item` will contain the menu item that you have clicked.